# Show with star symbols how many times a user have logged in

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a simple shell script showing how many times a user has logged in to their linux machine for at least one week. The output of the shell script should be like this:

```
2021-12-16
****
2021-12-15
**
2021-12-14
*******
```

I have tried this so far but it shows only numeric but i want showing `*` symbols.

```
user="$1"
last -F | grep "${user}" | sed -E "s/${user}.*(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) //" | awk   '{print $1"-"$2"-"$4}' | uniq -c
```

Any help?

Comment: As the `last` output varies from one system to another you should probably show an example output of your `last -F`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refactor all of this into a simple Awk script, where repeating a string *n* times is also easy.

```
user="$1"
last -F |
awk -v user="$1" 'BEGIN { split("Jan:Feb:Mar:Apr:May:Jun:Jul:Aug:Sep:Oct:Nov:Dec", m, ":");
    for(i=1; i<=12; i++) mon[m[i]] = sprintf("%02i", i) }
$1 == user { ++count[$8 "-" mon[$5] "-" sprintf("%02i", $6)] }
    END { for (date in count) {
        padded = sprintf("%-" count[date] "s", "*");
        gsub(/ /, "*", padded);
        print date, padded } }'
```

The `BEGIN` block creates an associative array `mon` which maps English month abbreviations to month numbers.

`sprintf("%02i", number)` produces the value of `number` with zero padding to two digits (i.e. adds a leading zero if `number` is a single digit).

The `$1 == user` condition matches the lines where the first field is equal to the user name we passed in. (Your original attempt had two related bugs here; it would look for the user name anywhere in the line, so if the user name happened to match on another field, it would erroneously match on that; and the regex you used would match a substring of a longer field).

When that matches, we just update the value in the associative array `count` whose key is the current date.

Finally, in the `END` block, we simply loop over the values in `count` and print them out. Again, we use `sprintf` to produce a field with a suitable length. We play a little trick here by space-padding to the specified width, because `sprintf` does that out of the box, and then replace the spaces with more asterisks.

Your desired output shows the asterisks on a separate line from the date; obviously, it's easy to change that if you like, but I would advise against it in favor of a format which is easy to sort, `grep`, etc (perhaps to then reformat into your desired final human-readable form).

Comment: `sprintf("%02i, i)` should be `sprintf("%02i", i)`. And as the OP want a separate line of stars, `print date; print padded` is probably a bit better than `print date, padded`. Last but not least, this will print the dates in an unpredictable order. I would not be surprised if this was an issue for the OP.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo. Indeed, the requirements are probably incomplete, but perhaps also within reach of fixing by the OP outside the scope of this question, maybe with the help of a few related Stack Overflow questions about common Awk problems.

Comment: I updated with a brief note about my decision to put the output for each date on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU sed you're almost there. Just pipe the output of `uniq -c` to this GNU sed command:

```
sed -En 's/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/printf "\2\n%\1s" ""/e;s/ /*/g;p'
```

Explanation: in the output of `uniq -c` we substitute a line like:

```
    6 Dec-15-2021
```

by:

```sh
printf "Dec-15-2021\n%6s" ""
```

and we use the `e` GNU sed flag (this is a GNU sed extension so you need GNU sed) to pass this to the shell. The output is:

```
Dec-15-2021
```

where the second line contains 6 spaces. This output is copied back into the sed pattern space. We finish by a global substitution of spaces by stars and print:

```
Dec-15-2021
******
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple soluction, using tempfile

```
#!/bin/bash
user="$1"
tempfile="/tmp/last.txt"
IFS='
'

last -F | grep "${user}"  | sed -E "s/"${user}".*(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) //" | awk   '{print $1"-"$2"-"$4}' | uniq -c > $tempfile

for LINE in $(cat $tempfile)
    do
        qtde=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1'})
        data=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2'})
        echo -e "$data "

        for ((i=1; i<=qtde; i++))
        do
                 echo -e "*\c"
        done
        echo -e "\n"
done
```

Comment: This has a rather unwieldy number of shell programming antipatterns. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the problems it points out for a start.