# Bash script-print a histogram with how many times i logged on

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to make a shell script which counts for each day how many times i logged on to my computer.Then print a simple histogram with * the number of connections per day.
Example:

```
./script.sh
2021-01-11  
**
2021-11-22  
**************
2021-11-01  
*
2021-10-14  
*
```

I have write this line

```
last --time-format iso | grep "^$(whoami)" | awk '{print $1 "\t" $4}' | awk -F "T" '{print $1 "\t" $2}' | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' | sort -k2 | uniq -c
```

The output:

```
k   2021-12-19
k   2021-12-19
k   2021-12-18
k   2021-12-17
k   2021-12-17
k   2021-12-17
k   2021-12-16
k   2021-12-15
k   2021-12-14
k   2021-12-13
k   2021-12-12
```

Now i think i need to put this into a **for loop** and **do** `awk $i 'BEGIN {print $3} END {print SOMETHINK I DONT KNOW}'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414783/bash-script-print-a-histogram-with-how-many-times-i-logged-on what happened? Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378793/show-with-star-symbols-how-many-times-a-user-have-logged-in

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```sh
last --time-format iso | awk -v username=$(whoami) '
    $1 == username { counts[$4] += 1 }
    END {
        n = asorti(counts, dates)
        while (++i <= n) {
            print dates[i]
            for (j = 1; j <= counts[dates[i]]; j++) printf "*"
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
'
```